# Configuration properties not autowired when used in request body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I'm using a particular class (ClassA) in my controller as the request body, but within that class, my autowired ConfigurationProperties is null.

**Controller:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1/")
public class XyzController {

    @Autowired
    ServiceXyz serviceXyz;

    @PostMapping(value = "/route")
    public void route(@RequestBody ClassA classA) {
        serviceXyz.methodAbc(classA);
    }
}
```

**ServiceXYZ:**

```java
@Service
public class ServiceXyz {

    public boolean methodAbc(ClassA classA) {
        return classA.methodA() && otherStuff();
    }
}
```

**ClassA.java:**

```java
@Component
public class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    public boolean methodA() {
        return fieldA.equals(applicationProperties.someProperty());
    }
}
```

**ApplicationProperties.java:**

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="stuff")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    // etc.
}
```

It's within `ClassA.methodA` that `applicationProperties` is `null`, even though everybody is marked with the correct annotations, and autowiring is working throughout the rest of the application.

Is it possible that this just doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowiring works for objects from Spring context. In your request object of `ClassA` is parsed from JSON I think and is not taken from Spring context.
You'd better change your code to make `ClassA` as simple DTO and inject `ApplicationProperties` into your service class.

You can change your `ClassA` to this

```
public class ClassA {

  public boolean methodA(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
      return fieldA.equals(applicationProperties.someProperty());
  }
}
```

And your service to this:

```
@Service
public class ServiceXyz {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

  public boolean methodAbc(ClassA classA) {
    return classA.methodA(applicationProperties) && otherStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the case, the inbound data is JSON being parsed by Jackson. I guess I naively assumed these DTOs would still be scanned and wired up.

Comment: @CharlesWood Added code sample that may work and fix your issue